# IMCE file browser not inserting selected image into image field

Tags: drupal, imce-file-browser

I'm working on new website (all modules are up to date) but for some reason IMCE file browser is not working well. For image fields in my content types for "file sources" I also check "IMCE file browser".

Then when I'm creating node in that type if I just upload file standard way it works well. But if I want to use IMCE file browser and select already uploaded image it all works up to last step. I click "File browser", then "browse" link, browser's popup appears, I select image, then click "Insert file" (or click on image preview - makes no difference), popup closes, but selected image is not inserted into my file field.

What can cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I had a simillar issue and following these steps made it work for me.

Try the following:

- [Clear your drupal cache](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/clearing-rebuilding-cache). This can often solve the problem as some items may not have been cached yet.
- Keep the [Chrome Developer Console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) open to see if there are any JS errors which may hint at the problem.
- In your CKEditor settings, make sure you tick "Plugin for inserting files from IMCE without image dialog"
- Ensure that the input field is using Full HTML
- If the above does not help try reinstalling IMCE and your WYSIWYG Editor such as CKEditor

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for help. But, I'm using wysiwyg module with CKE library, not CKE module. And when using wysiwyg editor image actually gets inserted well. Problem is with file fields - that's not working. Actually, I found out that for some (small) images it works...not sure exactly in what cases, but all this looks like some server side limitation to me..